# Character Encoding for when Reading Serial Port

Tags: java, character-encoding

I am using Java to read a serial port which is is connected to a weighing machine. The weighing machine sends data in the format `N   +   10 kg` with the 10 kg part being varied by the weight on the Weighing Scale.

At the moment, I am able to listen to the SerialPort events and get the data from the serial port as an `InputStream.` but I am getting the data in unknown characters which look something like `N?????+????????0???` (This is supposed to be `N     +       60 kg` which means that all the spaces have been replaced by question marks, same as `6` and `kg`. This is happening for all the weights.

I have tried to change the character encoding of the `InputStream` but I only get another unknown character (like a square)  in place of the question marks.

Below is a snippet code I have used.

```
InputStream is = thisPort.getInputStream();
while (true) {
   BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));
   String nextLine;
   try {
       nextLine = reader.readLine();
       System.out.println(nextLine);
   } catch (Exception e) {
       System.err.println(e.getMessage());
       if (e.getMessage().contains("shutdown or disconnected")) break;
   }
}
```

Please note that I am using `jSerialComm` jar to read the serial ports and `Java 8.`

Please let me know what I am not doing right because I am really stuck.

Comment: can you try with "UTF8" instead of "UTF-8" ? not sure if it makes a difference

Comment: Thanks @Bentaye I already tried that and getting the same result